# Set a default Cloud Run region? (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-run, region, google-cloud-shell

Whenever running **a Cloud Run service** on **Cloud Shell**:

```
gcloud run deploy myapp --image gcr.io/myproject-1831713/myapp
```

I'm always asked to input **a Cloud Run region** as shown below:

> Please specify a region:
> [1] asia-east1
> [2] asia-east2
> [3] asia-northeast1
> [4] asia-northeast2
> [5] asia-northeast3
> [6] asia-south1
> [7] asia-south2
> [8] asia-southeast1
> [9] asia-southeast2
> [10] australia-southeast1
> [11] australia-southeast2
> [12] europe-central2
> [13] europe-north1
> [14] europe-west1
> [15] europe-west2
> [16] europe-west3
> [17] europe-west4
> [18] europe-west6
> [19] northamerica-northeast1
> [20] northamerica-northeast2
> [21] southamerica-east1
> [22] southamerica-west1
> [23] us-central1
> [24] us-east1
> [25] us-east4
> [26] us-west1
> [27] us-west2
> [28] us-west3
> [29] us-west4
> [30] cancel
> Please enter your numeric choice:

So that I'm not asked to input **a Cloud Run region** whenever running **a Cloud Run service** on **Cloud Shell**, is it possible to set **a default Cloud Run region**? If possible, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to set **a default Cloud Run region** with this command below so that  you're not asked to input **a Cloud Run region** whenever running **a Cloud Run service** on **Cloud Shell**:

```
gcloud config set run/region <region>
```

So, for example, run this command below to set **the default Cloud Run region "asia-northeast1"** :

```
gcloud config set run/region asia-northeast1
```

In addition, you can check **your default Cloud Run region** with this command below:

```
gcloud config get run/region
```

Then, this is the result:

> Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-5343]
> asia-northeast1

And, you can check all configurations including **your default Cloud Run region** with this command below:

```
gcloud config list
```

Then, this is the result:

> [accessibility]
> screen_reader = True
> [component_manager]
> disable_update_check = True
> [compute]
> gce_metadata_read_timeout_sec = 30
> [core]
> account = myappdev0@gmail.com
> disable_usage_reporting = True
> project = myproject-383171
> [metrics]
> environment = devshell
> [run]
> region = asia-northeast1
>
> Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-5343]

In addition again, you can unset **your default Cloud Run region** with this command below:

```
gcloud config unset run/region
```

Then, check **your default Cloud Run region**:

```
gcloud config get run/region
```

Then, this is the result:

> Your active configuration is: [cloudshell-5343]
> (unset)

Comment: @FerreginaPelona - FYI: Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. There is even a checkbox for self answers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer The community can always upvote or downvote based upon quality, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So I think my comment is not needed anymore.